# Python pyfuglet modules installation

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

there is some modules that when im trying to install from pypI, like pyfiglet or Django framework, i'll saw some errors. how can i fix it? my python versio is 3.9.4

Comment: Please add what module you are trying to install with command and full error traceback

Comment: pyfiglet module with cmd. i used -m pip install pyfiglet

Comment: ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Payton\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 180, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "G:\Payton\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 204, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)

Comment: Don't add in comment section you can edit post as from the [docs](https://pypi.org/project/pyfiglet/) it does not support `python 3.9` so you have to downgrade it or use virtual environment

Answer (score 0):

For installing and checking the python module "pyfiglet" in VS Code, please refer to the following:

1. Please make sure that python is available, and select the required python environment in the lower left corner of VS Code.
2. Please use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new VS Code terminal, and check whether the python used by the terminal is the same as the lower left corner of VS Code: ( *python --version* )

   [image]
3. Then install the module "pyfiglet": ([pip install pyfiglet](https://pypi.org/project/pyfiglet/))
4. Check the installation of this module: (`pip show pyfiglet`)

Run:

[image]

Reference: [Getting Started with Python in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) and [Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).